# Azure functions scaling - resources (RAM, CPU, ...)

Tags: azure

I am looking for detailed information about the scaling of azure functions.
In the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) I have seen that there are a few plans with different scaling behaviors (manual/autoscale). But what does autoscale or manual mean regarding resources (RAM, CPU, ...) and so on?

They also write about instances. What do they do in the context: scaling of azure functions?

Answer (score 0):

> But what does autoscale or manual mean regarding resources (RAM, CPU, ...) and so on?

In general we have two types of scaling i.e, manual and custom autoscaling.

In Manual scaling, we have to manually change the number of instances to scale up or down every time.

Whereas in Custom Autoscaling, we have to configure the rules for autoscaling so that whenever the given scaling rules(metrics) what we provided for an application are met, then custom autoscaling will dynamically increase/decrease the total number of instances.

Generally, scaling is done with the help of Azure Monitor autoscale feature which can be applied only to Virtual Machine scale sets, Cloud Services, App Service - Web Apps and API Management services.

The below statement about Azure Functions, According to this document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/auto-scaling#configure-autoscaling-for-an-azure-solution),

> **Azure Functions** differs from the previous compute options, because you don't need to configure any autoscale rules. Instead, Azure Functions automatically allocates compute power when your code is running, scaling out as necessary to handle load. For more  information, see [Choose the correct hosting plan for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).

Refer this to know more about [scaling up an app in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-scale-up).

Comment: And if I have for example three instances, does that mean three Azure Functions are running in parallel?

Comment: if single function is taking longer time to execute function then autoscale will create a new instance to run another consecutive run.

Comment: Did you find any documentation that describes what a longer time is (for example 2 seconds?